# What are the three dots in a list range index?

Tags: python

I am reading other's code and saw this line:

```
pos_encoding = angle_rads[np.newaxis, ...]
```

This is the firs time I saw [xyz, ...]. What does the 3 dots mean in this list notation?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That won't tell you anything about how `angle_rads.__getitem__` interprets it.

Comment: You don't need to know what `...` is, only what `angle_rads` is to find its definition. (Knowing that `...` is the sole instance of the `ellipsis` class won't help you find that documentation.)

Comment: It's called an [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis). It's used to do extended slicing in `numpy` as explained in its documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing).